# UITableView not loading data with TabBar Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tableview in one of my controller. It is not loading data into custom labels and image view with tags. I checked each and every thing, delegates are attached and I am reloading the data in viewWillAppear. I do not understand, where is the problem. I added label and images and assign them tag. Only default label of tableview is showed.

```
NSString *cellIdentifier;
NSMutableArray *historyArray;

@implementation CloudHistory

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    historyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"history1",@"history2",@"history3",@"history4",nil];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Reload data in services table.
        [_historyTableView reloadData];
    });
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //Number of section in services table.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [historyArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *name = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:40];
    name.text =[historyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:44];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rtb_logo"];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Change the background color to stoker Cloud color.
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [UIView new];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor colorWithRed:116.0/255.0 green:174.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: is cellForRow is calling  ?

Comment: Yes, it is called.

Comment: give label and image CGrectMake(x,y,width,height)

Comment: But I implemented same in many controllers. There is some other error.

Comment: add self.tableview instead of tableview in front of dequeueReusableCell. I hope it will works

Comment: just reloadtableview

Comment: I am loading, check the code.  [_historyTableView reloadData];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can export the name and image , I think some of them maybe is invalid or nil .

```
UILabel *name = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:40];
NSLog(@"name = %@",name); // is it valid ?

UIImageView *image = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:44];
NSLog(@"image = %@", image); // is it valid ?
```

if some of them invalid or nil,you can do something like this:

```
    UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 80, 44)];
    name.text = @"name";
    [cell addSubview:name];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 44, 44)];
    imageView.image = image;
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
```

hope it helps.

Comment: As, I am using tag property and also you cannot connect custom labels within a cell to outlet.

Comment: you can use the cell textLabel like this: cell.textLabel.text = [historyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: I do not want to use default cell label. I need to add 4 custom labels.

Comment: you can export you cell subviews :NSLog(@"cell subviews = %@",cell.subviews); I guess your cell has not viewTag with 40 or 44 .

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a custom UITableViewCell using a xib file?
If so, you could register it in viewdidload.
Something like this

```
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"xibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Then your tableview can find your custom view outlets.

Hope this helps

Comment: No, just tableView cell from objects library.

Comment: If it's a standard UITableViewCell try to put the text in it's title property. Better not add labels and imageviews like that, they won't show up!  (Or maybe I misunderstood how you try to do it)

Comment: They show up. The default label shows up in UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a custom UITableViewCell with your UILabel and UIImageView? So you can access the cell property, like:

```
cell.name.text = [historyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rtb_logo"];
```

Anyway looks like your UILabel and UIImage is getting the values, but it's not setting them to your cell. To test you can log the value of the UILabel just to check. I don't know if it will work but have you tried this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *name = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:40];
    name.text =[historyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell viewWithTag:40] = name; // I don't know if this works

    // Check it out if the name.text is getting any value
    NSLog(@"UILabel %@",name.text);

    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:44];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rtb_logo"];
    [cell viewWithTag:44] = image; // I don't know if this works

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: That's not my requirement.